# The functional way of creating an array from properties on an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming

So basically here is what I have, which works as intended -

```
        let newList: any[] = [];

        for (let stuff of this.Stuff) {
            newList = newList.concat(stuff.food);
        }
```

So basically Stuff is an array of objects where each object has a property that is another object called food. I want to go through this array of Stuff and create a new array with each instance of food within it.

I don't think the way I have done it is bad, I'm just wondering for my own curiosity how someone would have done this without the for loop.

Cheers.

Comment: `let newList = this.Stuff.map(o => o.food)` will give you an array of `food` objects from `Stuff`

Comment: `stuff.food` is not an array, right? Then you shouldn't use `concat`, or at least wrap it first: `.concat([stuff.food])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`map` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
const newList = this.Stuff.map(stuff => stuff.food);
```

You shouldn't need to use continuous reassignment to a variable, and it's certainly not functional :-) Also, using `concat` repeatedly is pretty inefficient, you'd better have used `push` within the `for…of` loop. But `map` is still simpler and better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach as well using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method

```js
var arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];
var output = arr.reduce( function ( prev, curr ){ return prev.concat( curr ) } );
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can express this nicely with an added functional primitive

```
const prop = x => y => y[x];

const newList = this.Stuff.map(prop('food'));
```